# C# Read From Text File, New Line

Tags: c#, file-io

My code to write text to a file works perfectly...

```
        string path = @"./prefs.dat";
        string stringdir = textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, stringdir);
```

Then to read from the file I use this code which again works perfectly...

```
        Process test = new Process();
        string FileName = "prefs.dat";
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName);
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        lines.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        string s = lines[0];
        sr.Close();
        test.StartInfo.FileName = s;
        test.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        test.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        test.Start();
```

However when I want to read the 2nd line using the exact same code except changing...

```
       string s = lines[1];
```

Then it fails, I get a null result. When I look into further the error doesn't even see the 2nd line even though I clearly have two lines.

Comment: Because you are adding only first line to the list. You need to loop through the file till `EOF` not reach and keep adding the lines to the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ReadLine()` method reads one line at a time,you need to add all lines by using a while loop following way:

```
string line="";
while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   lines.Add(line);

}

string s = lines[1];
```

See [this MSDN article (**Reading a Text File One Line at a Time**) for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

The other way around can be to read all lines at once using [**ReadAllLines()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then access second line:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(stringdir);
string s = lines[1];
```

See [this MSDN article on **How to: Read From a Text File**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can also read all lines altogether

```
string[] lines =  System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("path");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get content of second line as `string s = lines[1];` you need to add that to the list first

```
    Process test = new Process();

    string FileName = "prefs.dat";
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName);
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    lines.Add(sr.ReadLine()); 
    lines.Add(sr.ReadLine());
    string s1 = lines[0];
    string s2 = lines[1]; // Now you can access second line
    sr.Close();
    test.StartInfo.FileName = s;
    test.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    test.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    test.Start();
```